# How to enable the resolve context switcher of a CPP file in CLion?

Tags: parsing, cmake, clion, profile

I have two files: `FastSweeping.h` and `FastSweeping.cpp`, which I compile using two CMake profiles: "Debug 2D" and "Debug 3D".  The problem I'm facing is that I don't get the correct parsing of `FastSweeping.cpp` when I switch from "Debug 2D" to "Debug 3D".  I noticed that the *Resolve Context* switch on the bottom right is disabled, and it always shows "Debug 2D", even if I select "Debug 3D" as the CMake compilation profile at the top right.

If I open `FastSweeping.h` the situation is different and (macro) parsing is fine.  I also noticed that the *Resolve Context* switch is enabled, and I can select between the "Debug 2D" and "Debug 3D" contexts at will.  Why is the *Resolve Context* disabled for the case of the `FastSweeping.cpp` source file?

Note that when I switch the CMake profile to "Debug 3D" at the top right menu, compilation and linking works well (even though the resolve context for `FastSweeping.cpp` is "stuck" in "Debug 3D").

I have perused the documentation for CLion, and I haven't found a reason as to why the IDE is not allowing to switch the context resolve for my `cpp` file.